# d3 js Hierarchical edge bundling Data Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, bundle-layout

I am trying to visualize url to targetURL using hierarchical edge bundling. What type of relation is required between these columns?

Here is [the sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999):

[image]

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/musakkhir/67oncb2t/1/).

I am getting an error as

```
TypeError: node.parent.children is undefined
```

Comment: next time someone asks for more information on your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475346/hierarchical-edge-bundling-data-format) please edit your question and do not open the same question again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in the docs for the [Bundle Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Bundle-Layout), the layout is applied to an array of *links*, each of which has a `source` and `target` property pointing to the nodes at the two ends of the link.  In addition, these two nodes each need a `parent` attribute that points to the parent node in the hierarchy.

This data is (ideally) coming from the [Cluster Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout), which positions the nodes before the links are bundled.  The cluster layout will produce the data needed by the bundle layout (the `cluster.nodes` function returns nodes with more than just the `parent` property and `cluster.links` returns the links with `source` and `target`).  This means you just need to make the cluster layout happy and you'll be fine.

There are a few problems with your code as written.  In general, rather than modifying your data to fit a visualization you copy-pasted from an example, it's better practice to update the various D3 accessors to use the format of the data you have.  That's why they're there.

The visualization you copied from is more consistent in its data cleanup, so you've introduced some issues there.  We'll just work around them, but you should probably spend some time getting it right.  The first issue is the error you noted: `TypeError: node.parent.children is undefined`.  This is because you're getting to line 1483 in `find` and trying to add a child to a list that doesn't exist.  We can go ahead and just power through here by adding a specific check for this (though, as mentioned, you should actually just clean up how this is handled):

```
if (typeof d.children === 'undefined') {
    d.children = []
}
```

Also you're adding a root node with the name of the empty string.  This is because on line 1481 you call `find` regardless of the length of the substring.  By checking the return value of the call to `lastIndexOf` you will know whether the node has a parent or not, and in the latter case, set `parent` to `null` (as [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) states, *parent - the parent node, or null for the root*).

Once we get past these issues, you'll start seeing a `TypeError: n is undefined`.  This is because your data is incomplete:  you have references to nodes that don't exist, so on line 1510 you add a link that doesn't have a `target` property, so when you try to bundle the links the layout fails.  This one can be ignored for the time being by only adding links to nodes that exist, but again, you probably should actually fix this rather than letting it be.

```
if (i in map) {
    imports.push({ source: map[d.name], target: map[i] });
}
```

The long and short of it is, read the docs, use your debugger, and don't copy-paste code without taking the time to understand it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musakkhir/67oncb2t/1/)

Comment: In jsfiddle `return map["webmetro.com"];` this code maps to root domain. Can I include root domain in graph also, which is not find in the current graph?